# Error en consultas PHP / SQL

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

Buenos días mi consulta es básica, estoy atorado al no saber cual es el error. Resulta que estoy realizando peticiones a una base de datos en un servidor de la siguiente forma

```
<?php
    $ranking = array();
    $mysqli = new mysqli("IP", "USER", "PASS", "DB");
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        echo "Falló la conexión con MySQL: (" . 
                $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . 
                $mysqli->connect_error;
    }
    else{
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM char");
        $stmt->execute();
        $resultados = $stmt->get_result();
        while ($fila = $resultados->fetch_assoc()) {
            $ranking[] = $fila;
        }
        return $ranking;
        
    }
```

Por motivos de seguridad no ingreso los datos personales. Resulta que en la creacion del mysqli al poner los datos de mi servidor a nivel local me funciona correctamente el código, el error es al momento de llamar al servidor con sus respectivas credenciales

El error que tengo al llamar el servidor es este

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function execute() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\api\rankingZeny.php:12 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\api\rankingZeny.php on line 12
```

Respuesta a nivel local

```
[{"rank":1,"name":"nidhoggur8","zeny":100000000,"account_id":2000014},{"rank":2,"name":"nidhoggur5","zeny":7894500,"account_id":2000013},{"rank":3,"name":"nidhoggur1","zeny":5555500,"account_id":2000009},{"rank":4,"name":"NicoAFV8","zeny":1000000,"account_id":2000010},{"rank":5,"name":"NicoAFV4","zeny":765500,"account_id":2000012},{"rank":6,"name":"nidhoggur4","zeny":256500,"account_id":2000011},{"rank":7,"name":"NicoAFV3","zeny":134500,"account_id":2000010},{"rank":8,"name":"NicoAFV2","zeny":7500,"account_id":2000004},{"rank":9,"name":"NicoAFV1","zeny":5500,"account_id":2000003}]
```

Estoy 100% seguro que me conecta con el servidor, solo que no me esta dando una respuesta

Cualquier idea sobre la solución estoy atento y agradecido

var_dump($mysqli) despues del prepare

```
object(mysqli)#1 (19) { ["affected_rows"]=> int(-1) ["client_info"]=> string(79) "mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407 - $Id: 3591daad22de08524295w1bd073aceeff11e6579 $" ["client_version"]=> int(50012) ["connect_errno"]=> int(0) ["connect_error"]=> NULL ["errno"]=> int(1064) ["error"]=> string(154) "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''char'' at line 1" ["error_list"]=> array(0) { } ["field_count"]=> int(0) ["host_info"]=> string(24) "IP via TCP/IP" ["info"]=> NULL ["insert_id"]=> int(0) ["server_info"]=> string(14) "5.5.65-MariaDB" ["server_version"]=> int(50565) ["stat"]=> string(141) "Uptime: 3819060 Threads: 8 Questions: 427227 Slow queries: 0 Opens: 833 Flush tables: 2 Open tables: 156 Queries per second avg: 0.111" ["sqlstate"]=> string(5) "00000" ["protocol_version"]=> int(10) ["thread_id"]=> int(21853) ["warning_count"]=> int(0) }
```

Comment: muestra `var_dump($mysqli)` despues del prepare

Comment: **¿Seguro que la tabla `char` existe en el servidor?** Puedes poner esto así para verificarlo: `if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM char")) {  //aquí tu bloque donde lees los datos } else {  echo "La tabla no existe"; }` El mensaje de error: *`Call to a member function execute() on boolean`* indica claramente que la consulta no se preparó (`$stmt` es un booleano con valor `false`), muy probablemente porque la tabla `char` no existe.

Comment: La tabla si existe en el servidor, respecto al var_dum me indica que es un error de syntax "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'char' at line 1"

Comment: @IgnacioFuentes puedes pegar el resultado de var_dump en la pregunta?

Comment: Puede que ese fallo de sintaxis se deba al nombre que elegiste para tu tabla, considerando que char es un tipo de dato, prueba ponerla así: `SELECT * FROM `char`;` bueno no se ve pero pon char entre backticks o comillas simples invertidas **``**

Comment: Como dice BetaM es una palabra reservada. Por eso mi insistencia del var_dump

Comment: Era como decia @BetaM con el tema de las `````

Comment: Bien visto @BetaM, el problema es que `char`  es una palabra reservada y en ese caso hay que poner el nombre de la tabla rodeado por comillas de identificación. En el marcado como duplicado este problema es explicado ampliamente.

Comment: siempre subestiman el poder de `var_dump`

Answer (score 3):

La solución fue colocar el nombre de la tabla entre *backticks* **`**

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM `char`");
```